# Передать аргументы через консоль

Tags: javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте. У меня есть несколько зада  по js. Сами задачи решены. Но  мне нужно их модифицировать так чтоб аргументы в них можно было передавать через консоль (пример: node task-2  аргументы)
Я пытался использовать process.argv[0] И это работает если аргумент один.
А что делать если несколько?  Как  в примерах ниже?

```
(function () {
    var inputString1 = 'A big red apple.';
    var inputString2 = 'RED is a registered trade mark.';
    var inputString3 = 'Red is his nickname.';
    var checkString = 'Red';

    function stringCheck(str, checkword) {
    checkword = checkword.toLowerCase();
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    if (~str.indexOf(checkword)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(stringCheck(inputString1, checkString));
console.log(stringCheck(inputString2, checkString));
console.log(stringCheck(inputString3, checkString));

})();
```

И вот такая

```
(function () {
 array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 45, 34, "sdds", 1.2];
 var max = "max";
 var min = "min";

 function findMinMax(arr, value) {
    var filterData = filterInput(arr);
    if (value == "min") {
        var arrLength = arr.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
            return Math.min.apply(null, filterData);
        }
    }
    if (value == "max") {
        var arrLengthM = arr.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < arrLengthM; j++) {
            return Math.max.apply(null, filterData);
        }
    }
}

function filterInput(arr) {
    var numberArr = arr.filter(function (numb) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(numb)) && isFinite(numb) && !(numb % 1);
    });
    return numberArr;
}

  findMinMax(array, max);

  console.log(findMinMax(array, max));
  console.log(findMinMax(array, min));
})();
```

И такая где аргумент это массив

```
(function () {
    var array = {
    "Value": 100,
    "Value2": 213,
    "Value3": 5350,
    "Value4": "string",
    "Value5": "string2",
    "Value6": NaN
};

function sumNumber(obj) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var value in array) {
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(array[value])) && isFinite(array[value])) {
            sum += array[value];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

sumNumber(array);
console.log(sumNumber(array));
})();
```

Comment: посмотри что у тебя лежит в `process.argv` когда ты передаешь несколько аргументов

Comment: @Grundy, он подерёт `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 45, 34, "sdds", 1.2]` на части так, что собирать замучаешься

Comment: @Qwertiy, наверняка все уже придумано :)

Comment: @Grundy, у меня не гуглится, как получить нераспаршенную командную строку :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, а разве нет каких нибудь модулей для работы с параметрами командной строки?

Comment: @Grundy, те, которые я потыкал, отдают только результат парсинга...

Comment: @Qwertiy, может просто строкой передавать и потом JSON.parse какой-нибудь?

Comment: @Grundy, да, но не экранировать же кавычки и пробелы в json'е... Нужно как-то получить все параметры запуска в виде одной строки, а не массива.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52783/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 0):

Решил этот вопрос используя process.argv[]

Первая:

```
 сonsole.log(stringCheck(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]));
```

Вторая.

```
 console.log(findMinMax([1, 2, -20, 3, 4, -5, 44, 200, -100, "string", {}], process.argv[2]));
```